# How to make sure no conflict between bookings?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a booking system. Using c#, how do I check that a booking does not conflict with existing booking? For example, the user cannot book if the room is booked during that timing. The check availability button is to check for any conflict with existing bookings in the database.

Database:

[image: Database]

Design:

[image: Design]

Code:

[image: Code]

Comment: For example an INSERT/UPDATE query with an `EXISTS` predicate in the conditions. Or a`SELECT` and afterwards either a message to the user or an `INSERT`, inside a transaction. Or a similar approach, depending on the database system used. Add more information and relevant code to your question, otherwise this is too broad a topic to generate useful answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is entirely up to you, but you'd need a `RoomIsAvailable` method. This would take in the `room_id` and the requested `start_time` and `end_time`.

```
bool RoomIsAvailable(int roomId, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) 
{
    // your implementation
}
```

This would then call an SQL query that would count the number of bookings for the room with that id, and had a start time before the requested end time and an end time after the requested start time. This would use some SQL, something like this.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(0) 
FROM Meeting 
WHERE 
    room_id = @RoomId AND 
    start_time < @EndTime AND 
    end_time > @StartTime
```

If the returned count from SQL is greater than 0 then you have a booking conflict.